# could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Tags: django, postgresql, tcp

My site is running well for some time and suddenly my postgres is not reachable:

```
django.db.utils:OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused   
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

what can be wrong?

I have debian jessie with 2GB RAM. Traffic is 20 users per second.

why is it happenning suddenly by itself?

db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'mydblalala',                     
        'USER': 'lilili',                      
        'PASSWORD': 'lalalal',                  
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      
        'PORT': '5432',                      
    }
}
```

Comment: Either the serve did not start up, or there is a firewall blocking the port. You could try `nmap -p 5432 -PN localhost` to find out. Or `telnet localhost 5432`

Comment: Can you drop the content of your postgresql.conf here ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost sure, give me a moment

Comment: @ClémentPrévost http://content.screencast.com/users/doniyor/folders/Jing/media/9b2e5b90-5114-4f30-aefe-7e7a7af5b89c/2016-01-18_2107.png

Comment: hmm. Do you see any postgres process running ? Can you still connect to it via command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your your database overview in heroku - Connection Settings - URL
copy that url and paste it in your settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default="<URL>")}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question was asked a long time ago. But maybe it will help someone. I've added a few words to **Jhr's** answer.
You can get the database (**DB**) in two ways:

1. pushing a project to **Heroku** (**DB** is automatically created);
2. creating it yourself by command `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`.

Anyway when you have **DB** you need to connect your **APP** with **DB** on **Heroku**. For this purpose I added in **settings.py**:

> `DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=‘URI of DB on Heroku’)}`

.
 **URI** can be found in two ways:

1. if **DB** already exists: **https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps** -> **Your App** -> click **Heroku Postgres** -> **Settings** -> **View Credentials** -> **URI**.
2. if not - you need to type the command

> `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

and after it type

> `heroku config -s | grep DATABASE_URL`

Finally, instead of "**URI of DB on Heroku**" insert **URI** of your **DB** on **Heroku**.